# How to Create Group and Give Permission to users in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am working on an e-commerce project where I have created a custom dashboard for adding products and others things. But my client requirement is to create an interface on the dashboard where I can create groups and give permissions to my staff users. Please give me suggestions to achieve my target in a proper way. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just use the built-in Django authentication system which is made for such cases https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/

Comment: ya sir i know built in authentication but when i show on display all permission in front end there showing models name like add_student,view_student i have 100 models it showing all models name i hope you can understand my point. is there any where without showing models name in permission ?

Comment: Using the Django Admin panel, you could create groups which hold the model permissions. This way for each new staff member you would only need to add them to the group for the collection of permissions they are entitled to.

Comment: but sir how i know which group have which permission that client can know this group should have permissions.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#groups

The `Group` model should have a descriptive name such as "inventory manager". This should be understandable for staff members. The model itself has a list of `Permission`, the application manager must understand how permissions work in order to configure them.